# How to doHeadless Pygame with SSH?

Tags: python, ssh, pygame, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to create a python script with pygame to control servos with a gamepad. I want to be able to do this without a display of any kind. I am running the script on a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B with Raspbian OS and to run scripts I am using SSH from bash terminal (I've tried on VS Code terminal and git-bash terminal) on a windows computer with OS Windows 8. I've seen some work arounds for headless pygame code:

https://www.pygame.org/wiki/HeadlessNoWindowsNeeded

https://gist.github.com/illume/f2fcdde9478aa3f1db8f3ee17359cf1c

[Pygame headless setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32900155/pygame-headless-setup)

[Pygame display init on headless Raspberry Pi Zero (Raspbian Buster Lite)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57418067/pygame-display-init-on-headless-raspberry-pi-zero-raspbian-buster-lite)

[Pygame on Pi running through Putty, no screen, no input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42602848/pygame-on-pi-running-through-putty-no-screen-no-input/42602917#42602917)

[Pygame on Pi running through Putty, no screen, no input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42602848/pygame-on-pi-running-through-putty-no-screen-no-input)

However, none have worked and I keep getting these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ps4ServoControl.py", line 15, in <module>
    pygame.display.init()
pygame.error: Unable to open a console terminal
```

or

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ps4ServoControl.py", line 63, in <module>
    for event in pygame.event.get():
pygame.error: video system not initialized
```

I've tried every variation of the following lines:

```
os.environ["SDL_VIDEODRIVER"] = "dummy"
os.putenv('SDL_VIDEODRIVER', 'fbcon')
os.putenv('DISPLAY', ':0.0')
pygame.display.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1,1))
```

Is it just because I'm trying to do this with SSH? I'm not sure how else to test my scripts without doing a remote desktop, but again, I don't want to have to pull up a screen somewhere when I get the script working. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, pygame is built on the premise that you have a screen. I believe the event system requires a screen (hence the `pygame.error: video system not initialized`, which means you haven't initialized the screen). At least when I last saw this type of question, it wasn't possible to use pygame without it.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman - It was definitely possible last year.  I was using it for some sound stuff, but after updating everything, I'm crashing.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was headless and using pygame for sounds.  The code you showed used to work for me, but after updating this year I was getting the same error.  I resolved it by commenting out the following lines:

```
pygame.display.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1,1))
```

Everything seems to be fine without them.